# Diferenco inter "riski" kaj "aŭdaci"?

Tags: word-difference

Ekzistas diferenco inter "riski" kaj "aŭdaci"? Lau [Glosbe](https://en.glosbe.com/eo/en) ambaŭ estas sama (to dare, to be audacious). Ekzistas okazoj kie vi uzus unu anstataŭ la aliaj aŭ ĉu vi povas uzi ili interŝangeble?

Is there a difference between "riski" and "aŭdaci"? According to Glosbe both are the same (to dare, to be audacious). Are there times where you would use one instead of the other or can you use them interchangeably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komparu la difinojn en PIV. Laŭ PIV la baza formo de "aŭdac/" estas la adjektivo [aŭdaca](https://vortaro.net/#a%C5%ADdaca_kd)

> Riskema fari ion malgraŭ danĝeroj, malhelpoj, sociaj k moralaj premo

de kiu oni povas derivi verbon aŭdaci

> Konduti aŭdace

Kontraste la baza formo de "risk/" estas la verbo [riski](https://vortaro.net/#riski_kd), kiu havas **tri** difinojn:

> 1. Elmeti ion al necerto aŭ danĝero: *riski sian vivon en batalo*
> 2. Elmeti sin al la ebleco de bedaŭrinda okazaĵo: *en tiu afero ĉiuj riskas egale la morton*
> 3. Kuraĝi fari ion malgraŭ la ebleco de malsukceso aŭ malbona konsekvenco: *la komitato ne riskos preni sur sin mem tiun taskon*

Laŭ mia kompreno nur la tria difino similas al la difino de "aŭdaci". Do "riski" estas pli vaste uzebla.

Krome mi serĉis en [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com) kaj trovis nur 430 trafojn de "aŭdac". Inter 10 milionoj da vortoj tio estas neniom. La nombro de trafoj de "risk" estas pli ol mil, la supra limo de la serĉo. Do "aŭdaci" estas malpli uzata, sekve malpli konata (ekz. mi ne sciis, kion ĝi signifas antaŭ ol mi legis PIV-on).

Comment: Ekzemploj de aliaj signifoj de **riski** estus klariga: _Sen masko oni riskas koronviruson_,

Comment: Do ĉu la tradukoj sur https://glosbe.com/en/eo/dare estas akcepteblaj tradukoj por "dare" aŭ ĉu mi devas uzi vortaro.net anstataŭ? Glosbe estas komunuma submetita retpaĝo. Mi nur uzas Glosbe ĉar ĝi povas traduki inter multaj da lingvoj.

Comment: @jastako, la Fundamento kaj la Akademia vortaro estas la plej altrangaj. Multaj rigardas, ke inter la aliaj PIV estas la plej altranga. Mi ne uzas Glosbe-n, do mi ne povas diri, kiel bonaj ĝiaj tradukoj estas. Kutime estas bone kompari difinojn kaj ekzemplojn en vortaroj. Se vi volas uzi multlingvajn vortarojn, serĉu ankaŭ en [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/).

Comment: @JoopEggen, mi aldonis.

Comment: Mi cxefe vidis ”auxdaci” en kunteksto kun emfazo je sociaj normoj/premoj, kaj kun suficxe negativa sxargxo. Estas la signifo de la angla ”dare” en frazo kiel ”How dare you!”

Comment: La angla vorto "to dare" estas multsignifa, ĉar ĝi povas ankaŭ havi la sencon de [_arogi_](https://vortaro.net/#arogi_k) de Z mem: malhumile postuli, pretendi pri nemeritita honoro aŭ privilegio.

Comment: Laŭ mi ne estas tre informdone kompari nombron de aperoj en Tekstaro inter Fundamentaj kaj lastatempe oficiale aldonitaj radikoj.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, se vi indikas, ke oni aldonis _aŭdac/_ en la oka oficiala aldono, tiu aldono estas de la jaro 1974, do preskaŭ antaŭ 50 jaroj. Mi ne konsideras, ke tio estas "lastatempe".

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas La oka estas, ĝis nun, la antaŭlasta. Cetere: Universala vortaro - 1894, Oka aldono 1974. Ĉiuokaze, kiun ajn (pli taŭgan) adjektivon oni elektas por la oka aldono, la fakto restas ke oni ne devus opinii elementon malpli uzata, **nur** pro ĝiaj aperoj en Tekstaro. Ne nur por la 80 jaroj inter iliaj "oficialigoj", sed ankaŭ pro tio ke el la verkoj en Tekstaro, nur triono (plimalpi) estas post 1974. En diskuto pri signifnuanco (inter oficialaj elementoj) mi ne bone vidas la rolon de la nombro de aperoj.

Answer (score 3):

Vi povas pensi pri `aŭdac/i` ([8OA](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oka_Oficiala_Aldono_al_la_Universala_Vortaro)) iel kiel `kuraĝi riski` aŭ `kuraĝi malgraŭ risko`.

Do, depende de la kunteksto vi povas uzi ĉŭ unu ĉu la alian. `Aŭdac/` rilatas la agon kaj substrekas kuraĝon dum `risk/` rilatas kaj substrekas la eblon perdi. Oni aŭdacas vole, sed povas riski senkonscie.

```
Ŝi aŭdacis salti el moviĝanta aŭto
```

Ŝi konis la riskon kaj tamen kuraĝis fari tion.

```
Ŝi riskis sian vivon per salto el moviĝanta aŭto
```

Ĉu ŝi konis la riskon aŭ ne, oni ne scias